# SwaggerEditor: I want to pass user's email in the body structure and not URL for authentication

Tags: rest, swagger

I'm trying to pass an email address in the API call for authentication:

```
paths:
 /auth:
    post:
     tags: 
     summary:
     parameters: 
      name: emailAdd
      in: query
      schema: 
       type: string
```

....and so on and so forth

but the email is still passed in the url when I test it in Swagger - it's a bad practice so I would rather it wasn't in the URL and instead be like this:

```
[
   {
    "name:jdoe@homework.com
   }
    ]
```

but the code is not working - could someone please help?

Comment: Check out https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/

Comment: I think you should use quotes. `"name": "jdoe@homework.com"`